# Passing a string in javascript and retrieving it through php file

Tags: php, javascript

I am passing a string to a javascript through call by reference. The string is a text retrieved from a textarea field. The problem is that a single word is retrieved properly, but when i send multiple text it shows a problem. the sample code is like this in a php file,

```
<input type=button onclick="send(txt.value,123,456)">
```

The txt is the name of textarea field. If i type hello in the field and send it works prorperly but whenever i type string like hello india, it gives a problem and nothing is retrieved