# Passing a string to a javascript and retrieving it further

Tags: php, javascript

I am passing a string to a javascript through call by reference. The string is a text retrieved from a textarea field. The problem is that a single word is retrieved properly, but when I send multiple text it shows a problem. The sample code is like this in a php file,
The txt is the name of textarea field. If I type hello in the field and send it works properly but whenever I type string like "hello india", it gives a problem and nothing is retrieved

Sample code for post.php is like this :

```
<?php
$msg=$_GET['msg'];
$v1=$_GET['v1'];
$v2=$_GET['v2'];
    <textarea name="txt" id="txt">
    <input type=button onclick="send(txt.value,123,456)">
?>
```

The send() method is not a standard method. Its a custom method which passes variables to a file through GET method. The txt is the name of the textarea column. The send method works like this:

```
function send(str,var1,var2)
{
$('#loader').html('loading');
$('#postarea').load('post.php?msg='+str+'&v1='+var1+'&v2='+var2);
}
```

Comment: would be nice to see send() . Did you encode txt.value before sending it?

Comment: Sample code is like this : <input type=button onclick="send(txt.value,123,456)">

Comment: Could give a more complete code sample? You can edit your question. Where does PHP come into play?

Comment: What is in send() method?  It's not a standard JavaScript function.  So your problem should be somewhere in that custom method.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848683/passing-a-string-in-javascript-and-retrieving-it-through-php-file

Comment: Oh, why do you post your question a second time? This won't help you and is not how SO works. Please comment on answers in your original question, describe why something might not work and clarify your original question.

Comment: @Sanket Raut: You should have clarified your original question. But anyway, what you have is not valid PHP. And the answer to your problem was already given in your previous question: Use `escape(txt.value)`.

Comment: how to encode txt.value?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ajax to send the string that is probably the culpritt.

Use escape(string) to URL encode the string.

Also, if you use firefox, a addon called firebug and Live HTTP Headers are gold when debugging.

With Livehttpheaders you can se every call and respons from the server even if your script should ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below, its working fine its retrieving the data from text area correctly. i think there's some problem in the line `'$('#loader').html('loading')
'` u have added in JS.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send(str,var1,var2) {
    alert(str);
}
</script>

<textarea name="txt" id="txt"> </textarea>
<input type=button onclick="send(txt.value,123,456)">
```